# Installing Ubuntu with windows, Need help with partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

i am trying to make a dual boot system. My laptop currently has windows 10 and i  have downloaded a copy and made a bootable pen drive of ubuntu 16. Can somebody help me and direct me on how to use " somethign else" option properly and create what partitions.?

Current partitions : 
C: 240GB ( with windows installed) 
D: 312 GB for movies and stuff 
Z: 388 GB for more stuff 
And 30 GB of unallocated space.

Comment: Install ubuntu on the allocated space. You might also need another 4GB for swap.

Comment: What space is allocated space ? I would like to create a partition from unallocated space and use it to store Ubuntu OS. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

[image: From http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html]

If you see the similar page(or whatever you call it), then you're on the right track. Right click the **unallocated** space, you should see `New` from the right-click menu. Select it then you should know what to do. Remember the file system must be `ext4`. You may also need another 4GB(depending on your RAM) and set the file system as `swap`.
Now click on install then you're done. If you are unable to boot into Ubuntu, try boot into the live edition again, then run `boot-repair`. Read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I created following partitions removing my 312GB partition and 30GB unallocated space. 1st one was 50GB for ubuntu ext4 type with ( /) as mount point. Next one was 16GB for swap and remaining for stuff as ext4 with ( /home).. Also 1 MB of something called  " boot something " . Last 1MB partition was adviced by the installer. All was done and then i restarted. I am still directly moving into windows.
Now the live session is the option while installing ubuntu ?

Comment: Yes it is. Run boot repair and let it solve your remaining problem